# Is it possible to disable TSLint in tslint.json?

Tags: tslint, react-scripts

I use `react-scripts-ts` to generate React App and it supplies TSLint.

It seems like there's no option to tell `react-scripts-ts` to exclude TSLint from the build pipeline. Is it possible to disable TSLint via `tslint.json`?

P.S.

It's possible to disable it by adding comment to the file, but I don't want to add such comment to every TS file in the project.

Comment: how do you disable for a single file? (comment what?=

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you don't want any TSLint rules to be enforced and are prepared to edit the `tslint.json` file, you can just set its content to:

```
{}
```

With no rules defined, you will see this message written to the console:

```
No valid rules have been specified
```

But the TSLint process with terminate with an exit code of `0` and should not interfere with your build pipeline.

Or, if the message bugs you, define a single rule that's switched off:

```
{ "rules": { "no-var-keyword": false } }
```

Comment: Does this still work? (it doesn't for me - Failed to compile due to an unused var :(

Comment: The TSLint [`no-var-keyword` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-var-keyword/) and config have not changed. It's possible that something in `react-scripts-ts` has changed and I don't have the answer to that.

Answer (score 6):

Using @cartant's answer, I got some annoying output in the console saying something like 'Tried to lint a file, but found no valid/enabled rules...' for every single file in my project.

Anyways, in my tslint.json file, if I changed the extends property:

```
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
  ],
```

to be an empty array:

```
  "extends": [],
```

It turned everything off for me and there was no longer any lint related warnings or noise in the console.